scp from remote Linux server to local windows 11 machine returning "no such file or directory"
So I'm trying to download some data from a remote linux server onto my (unfortunately) windows 11 machine using the scp command in windows powershell. While I can send data to the server just fine, whenever I attempt to download data from the server it tells me that there is no such directory... for the files I'm trying to download... on the machine I'm trying to download them to.
One would expect a message like D:/Python Programs/time/etc: No such file or directory to have a typo or something in it but instead I get back
D:/Python Programs/time/1644116132/target_file1:   No such file or directory for about as many files are contained within the folder before it begins to try and download log.txt... to no avail, staying at a rate of 0kb/s.
Do note that anything with the in line code text is intentional and does not have actual quotes in it. I thought it would improve contrast but if it does not I will edit my post.
The code I used (with modifications for privacy) looks like this (after a suggestion made by Chris Davies):
scp -r root@host.etc.edu:/data/time/filepath/mast/files/1644116132/ "D:/Python Programs/time/"
Allegedly this is all it should take. While I could theoretically test if I can send it from the remote machine to the local one using ssh, I don't know if it would be worth the effort or if it will even work. I've looked all around for people experiencing similar problems but I literally can find no one. I've tried reversing the slashes on the windows file path but, again, the problem is that for some reason the program is expecting the files it's supposed to be copying over to already be there and somehow gets stuck.
It seems to find the correct files (1644116132/file1 etc.) but fails to send the data or the data fails to copy or something. As far as I can tell, this is a new problem related to scp and I can't find any answers to even related things on this subject.
I should note that the drive location isn't an issue either, as I've tried literally sending the data directly to JUST the path: C:/ but the problem persisted. This also implies that it's less likely to be an issue with quotation mark formatting.
EDIT: This has been solved by simply just working on the server, I haven't found a fix but... I mean if you're having this problem just work on the host by ssh-ing into it. I'll leave this open in case someone figures out the answer but for now it's technically solved.

Hi, I've tried adding the dot to the end of the source path but the same error occurs unfortunately.

Did you copy/paste the exact command here? Because I see "fancy quotes" that may be screwing something up... I'd try to set up a symlink to avoid spaces in paths and at least remove that from the list of things that could be failing.

@AaronD.Marasco I'm not quite sure what you mean by fancy quotes, BUT the command line I'm inputting without ANY fancy text things is:
scp -r root@host.etc.edu:/data/time/filepath/mast/files/1644116132/ ‘D:/Python Programs/TIME/’
I should also note that it's unlikely to be anything with quotation marks as I previously attempted to simply download the file onto the local path C:/ to no avail. I will edit and put this into the main body.

That comment still has smart single quotes in it. You MUST use plain double quotes

@AaronD.Marasco I apologize, given the recent comment of Chris the new updated version of the input code (as should be seen in the main body) is: scp -r root@host.etc.edu:/data/time/filepath/mast/files/1644116132/ "D:/Python Programs/TIME/"

Does it work if you run the command from the target directory and just do scp -r root@host.etc.edu:/data/time/filepath/mast/files/1644116132/ .?

@terdon I have now just tried variations of that (moving that period around a bit and re-including the destination filepath) as well as your exact suggestion, and it unfortunately didn't work. Thanks anyways though, I seriously appreciate everyone's help in this!

Windows CMD is really picky over "double quotes" vs 'single quotes'. (And that's not even considering the ‘smart quotes’ in the question itself.)
This works for me from Windows 11 CMD, using its standard scp:
scp -r remoteHost:bin/ "C:/Users/Chris/OneDrive …/target"

This version fails under exactly the same scenario, reporting an error caused by the quotes not managing the space-filled target pathname as a single entity:
scp  -r remoteHost:bin/ 'C:/Users/Chris/OneDrive …/target'
…/target': No such file or directory

In your situation, and assuming the smart quotes are really plain single quotes, I would expect the error message to be
Programs/time/': No such file or directory

And since the Windows version of scp is not yet using SFTP this command variant with a dot at the end of the source path also fails:
scp -r remoteHost:bin/. "C:/Users/Chris/OneDrive …/target"
error: unexpected filename: .


I don't know exactly what smart quotes are... If you are referring to the code I have, I put it in as "in-line code" from the editor when making the post. I don't think they are present... or at least not in the way this answer is suggesting as quotes are not placed within the error text... i.e. it returns D:/blah_blah/target: No such file or directory
The main problem is that I tried importing the data directly to my C:/ drive, no quotes... same problem. So while it's plausibly due to the quotations, it's not super high on my list.

There are three types of visible quotes in that first paragraph of my answer. (And another set that drives the formatting for CMD and as a consequence is not directly visible.) You must use plain double quotes for path names like yours that contain spaces. Not single quotes. Not smart quotes. Not backtick quotes.

I just tried that and it didn't work. I'm pretty sure that all I needed to do was input double quotes (shift + ' ) using my keyboard... did I still use smart quotes there or is it something else?

Your question doesn't show double quotes. We can only answer based on what you show us. If your question doesn't match your reality then it's quite probable the answers won't help you either

I mean fair enough but while I can change the quotes the problem still remains is all. I'll go ahead and change that now but I unfortunately don't know if it's an issue with the location (as I accidentally reversed the order and sent data to the remote server AND I've had the problem when no quotations were involved at all when trying to troubleshoot. I hope that can help narrow it down a bit as I add those things to my post.

"Windows CMD is really picky" – Because it's not CMD what interprets quotes and such. See "The situation is somewhat more complicated" in this answer.
